# What is the difference between using the Sitecore gutter to unlock an item and using the command button in the Sitecore Ribbon?

Tags: content-editor, powershell, ribbon

I am working on creating an SPE version of unlocking an item in Sitecore I can assign to content editors so an administrator does not have to do it.  Unlocking an item using the Sitecore ribbon seems to not work while using Sitecore's gutter works fine.  I am trying to determine what the difference is between both mechanisms.  I know how to create a quick SPE type button but when I tried to use that, it behaved like the button in the ribbon so I am trying to figure out if the mechanism used in the gutter is different, how is it different and how I can expose that to content editors so they can unlock their own items and not always reach out to an administrator.  This is in Sitecore 9.0.2.

Comment: SPE comes with an Elevated Unlock tool. Have you explored how that is configured?

Comment: not yet... I did try using SPE steps for running the mechanism as an admin but that did not get me to a place where I can execute the code successfully...